# Gratia package: probability instead of log odds for plotting generalized additive model (GAM)

Tags: ggplot2, plot, gam

I was trying to plot a logistic GAM model using the gratia package (since it uses ggplot2), however I would like the effects (or partial effects) to be plotted in terms of probabilities instead of log odds.

I have tried by hand using probabilities, however I prefer to use the gratia package. Would there be a way to plot the probabilities specifically using the package?

The model (I created some data):

```
set.seed(1)
Perf1 <- rlnorm(100)
Sex <- sample(c(rep(1, 40), rep(0, 60)))
set.seed(2)
Group <- sample(c(rep(1, 30), rep(0, 70)))
set.seed(3)
Perf2 <- rlnorm(200)
G <- sample(c(rep(1, 20), rep(0, 80)))
Age <- sample(c(rep(7, 15), rep(8, 20), rep(9, 30), rep(10, 10), rep(11, 15), rep(12, 10)))



sample_data <-data.frame(Age = Age,
                         Sex = Sex,
                         G = G,
                         Group = Group,
                         Perf1 = Perf1,
                         Perf2 = Perf1
)

gam_fit <- gam(Group ~ Age + Sex + G + s(Perf1, k = 20) +
      s(Perf2, k = 20),
    data = sample_data, 
    family = "binomial",
    method="REML", select = F)

draw(gam_fit, parametric = T)
```

Plotting using gratia:

[gam_fit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DsWHh.png)

The effect or partial effect is on the log odds scale, while I would like probabilities instead, but I am unsure how to achieve this.

Comment: Hi @yentl19, could you please share what you already have tried and your data using `dput()`? So we can help you better.

Comment: @Quinten thank you very much for your response, I am very new to posting questions so I hope my edits are helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to add the model constant term and transform by the inverse of the link function:

```r
draw(gam_fit, constant = coef(gam_fit)[1], fun = inv_link(gam_fit))
```

(and I'm not sure if `constant` or `fun` work on the parametric terms just now.)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Just so that I understand completely: why are you also indicating the constant (intercept)? And would retrieving the odds ratios be achieved by using `exp` instead of `inv_link`?

Comment: You need the model intercept (constant) to get probabilities. Yes, using `exp` would give odds, and in the case you could leave out the constant.