# How to plot logistic probability for custom generalized additive model (GAM) plot?

Tags: r, regression, gam, mgcv, gratia

I realize that there is already a question pertaining to this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71694817/gratia-package-probability-instead-of-log-odds-for-plotting-generalized-additiv). However, I'm not looking to use the `draw` function and would prefer to build up the plot by scratch like shown [here](https://gavinsimpson.github.io/gratia/articles/custom-plotting.html). However, the plot shown in the link doesn't show how to do this with logistic probability. I show an example that gets close, but only plots by the link function.

```
#### Libraries and Data ####
library(mgcv)
library(gamair)
library(tidyverse)
data("wesdr")

#### Fit Model ####
fit <- gam(
  ret ~ s(dur),
  method = "REML",
  family = binomial,
  data = wesdr
)

#### Evaluate the Smooths ####
sm <- smooth_estimates(fit) %>%
  add_confint()
sm

#### Add Partial Residuals ####
wesdr <- wesdr %>% 
  add_partial_residuals(fit)

#### Plot ####
p <- sm %>%
  filter(smooth == "s(dur)") %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_rug(aes(x = dur),
           data = wesdr,
           sides = "b", 
           length = grid::unit(0.02, "npc")) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = lower_ci, 
                  ymax = upper_ci,
                  x = dur),
              alpha = 0.2) +
  geom_line(aes(x = dur,
                y = est),
            lwd = 1.2) +
  labs(y = "Partial effect",
       title = "s(dur)")
p
```

[image]

Specifically, I'm looking for something functionally equivalent to this:

```
plot(fit,
     trans = plogis,
     shift = coef(fit)[1])
```

[image]

Any advice on how to get the probability plot?

##### Edit

I realize I wasn't precise about what I needed. The answer given is good, but I'm considering the most general-case use where a logistic GAM has multiple predictors. So I need a plot based off a model like this:

```
#### Fit Model ####
fit <- gam(
  ret 
  ~ s(dur)
  + s(bmi),
  method = "REML",
  family = binomial,
  data = wesdr
)
```

To account for the average value of other predictors, I need to include the intercept into the plot, which is why I originally used `shift` in the `plot.gam` function in base R.

Comment: Why not look at the code for `plot.gam`?

Comment: I'm already familiar with `plot.gam`. The issue though is that the arguments that exist like `trans` do not exist immediately in `ggplot`. I'm very confident there is an easy way to transform the data after it's been fit, but I'm a bit confused on how.

Comment: The *intercept* is not "the average of the other predictors". The intercept is the average of the response (in this case) on the link scale. What do you want? Do you want to draw the partial effect of `s(dur)` but on the probability scale? Of do you want to draw the estimated response on the probability scale as a function of `dur` (either ignoring the effect of `s(bmi)` or setting `bmi` to some fixed, constant value)?

Comment: Sorry that was poor wording on my part. I mean each partial effect plot should be interpreted as showing the probability of the outcome if all other variables were at their average value. I recall the shift in the base R plot above being taught that way in Noam Ross's course, so that is what I'm after in the ggplot version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general way to do this is to predict from the model at the values you want. Using your extended example,

```r
library("gratia")
library("mgcv")
data("wesdr", package = "gamair")
fit <- gam(ret ~ s(dur) + s(bmi),
           data = wesdr, method = "REML", family = binomial)
```

Create a data slice at the values of the covariates you want. If you just specify `dur` in the data slice then you will get the other covariate, `bmi` set to the value of the observation closest to the median of `bmi` in the training data

```r
ds1 <- data_slice(fit, dur = evenly(dur, n = 100))
```

But it is easy to specify other values; you mentioned setting the other covariates to their mean:

```r
ds2 <- data_slice(fit, dur = evenly(dur, n = 100), bmi = mean(bmi))
```

Then you `predict()`:

```r
fv2 <- fitted_values(fit, data = ds2, scale = "response")
```

Then plot

```r
library("ggplot2")

fv2 |>
  ggplot(aes(x = dur, y = fitted)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(x = dur, ymin = lower, ymax = upper),
              inherit.aes = FALSE, alpha = 0.2) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_rug(data = wesdr, aes(x = dur), sides = "b", inherit.aes = FALSE, 
           length = grid::unit(0.01, "npc"), alpha = 0.5)
```

which produces

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The link function returns log odds. Since odds are just `p / (1 - p)`, then log odds are `log(p / (1 - p))`. The inverse is `exp(odds) / (1 + exp(odds))`. So we can just do:

```r
p$data <- mutate(p$data, across(c(est, lower_ci, upper_ci), ~exp(.x)/(1 + exp(.x))))

p + ylim(c(0, 1))
```

[image]

To get the partial effect by hand when you have multiple independent variables, you can predict the outcome at the mean of the other variables while only changing the variable of interest. Here, we'll dress up the ggplot to make it look more like the base R plot:

```r
fit <- gam(
  ret 
  ~ s(dur)
  + s(bmi),
  method = "REML",
  family = binomial,
  data = wesdr
)

newdata <- data.frame(dur = 0:55, bmi = mean(wesdr$bmi))

pred <- predict(fit, newdata, se.fit = TRUE)

newdata$ret <- exp(pred$fit) / (1 + exp(pred$fit))

newdata$upper <- exp(pred$fit + 1.96 * pred$se.fit) / 
                 (1 + exp(pred$fit + 1.96 * pred$se.fit))

newdata$lower <- exp(pred$fit - 1.96 * pred$se.fit) / 
                 (1 + exp(pred$fit - 1.96 * pred$se.fit))

ggplot(newdata, aes(x = dur)) +
  geom_rug(data = wesdr, sides = "b", length = grid::unit(0.02, "npc"), 
           lwd = 0.2, col = "gray60") +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper), alpha = 0, linetype = 2,
              color = "black") +
  geom_line(aes(y = ret), lwd = 1.2) +
  labs(y = "Partial effect", title = "s(dur)") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = 0.2 * 1:5) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 10 * 0:5) +
  theme_classic(base_size = 20)
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for getting close to what I need. This achieves what I wanted for a single variable, but as I mentioned in the comments, I also need to include the intercept to account for the average value of other predictors. I will edit my question to make that point more clear.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use `predict.gam` using `type='link'` and `se=TRUE`

```
mod <- gam(
  ret ~ s(dur),
  method = "REML",
  family = binomial,
  data = wesdr
)
```

`pred <- predict.gam(mod, wesdr, type = "link", se=TRUE)`

Then use the inverse link to scale appropriately

```
wesdr %>% 
  mutate(fit = mod$family$linkinv(pred$fit),
         lci = mod$family$linkinv(pred$fit - 1.96 * pred$se.fit),
         uci = mod$family$linkinv(pred$fit + 1.96 * pred$se.fit)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(dur, fit)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=lci, ymax = uci), alpha = 0.3) +
  geom_rug(aes(x=dur), sides = "b", 
           length = grid::unit(0.02, "npc"))
```

Comment: This works (to an extent) for a model with a single variable (if you have uneven spacing of observations over the range of the covariate then you won't get a nice smooth spline in the plot), but isn't going to work for a model with multiple terms - you need to generate data varying `dur` but holding the other covariates at representative values.